# Overlapping CSS flexbox items in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

What's the correct CSS to force Safari to not overlap flex items within a default flex container?

Safari seems to give too much width to flex items with lots of content.

**Safari:** (v8.0.8 on Mac OS X 10.10.5 Yosemite)
[image: flex-items-safari.png]

The flex items display fine in Chrome and Firefox.

**Chrome:**
[image]

**CSS:**

```
main {
   display: flex;
   border: 3px solid silver;
   }
main >div {
   background-color: plum;
   margin: 10px;
   }
```

**HTML:**

```
<main>
   <div>
      Doh!!!!!!!!!!!
   </div>
   <div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
      dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
   </div>
</main>
```

Fiddle with the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/LL05grus/6

Comment: It appears this issue is now fixed.  Tested with **Safari 10.0** on **macOS 10.12 Sierra**.

Comment: Yes it seems like the problem has been resolved in all latest versions and the asked question is quite old/outdated.

Comment: @DemPilafian But I still encounter this issue with **Safari 12.1.2** on **macOS 10.14 Mojave**

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The element is shrinking. You need to set the `flex-shrink` property to `0` on the shrinking element.

```
main >div:first-child {
  -webkit-flex: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: That was really helpful! However, I had to go with flex: 0 0 auto to solve the issue on my side.

Comment: Had the same issue, one of the flex items did not get enough space on safari mobile. This seems to solve it for me. Thanks

Comment: You can also add `flex-shrink: 0;` to the element it stop it from getting smaller than its minimum size.

Comment: Had an overlapping problem in mobile safari 9.5. this fixed it like a charm! thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I also had a similar issue where flex box direction changed to column overlapped items on iPad. The issue was with the `flex: 0 1 0;` property applied to child element. Give the base value auto. `flex: 0 1 auto;`

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.parent .child{
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While I can no longer replicate the issue of OP using Safari 14.0.2, I still observe in some cases where Safari would over-shrink elements that other browsers like Safari and Firefox do not.

Although setting `flex-shrink: 0;` works, in some cases, we intend to use like `flex: 0 1 15%` where we want shrinking to happen, but without the over-shrinking.

Workaround seems to work for me:

`min-height: min-content` (or `min-width`)