# Flexbox columns overlap in Safari 10

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I'm working on a simple layout using flexbox that works in Chrome, but in Safari, the heights of elements seem off.

There is a minimal example fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/6h84h2w6/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="menu">
    <div class="menu-item">
      Menu item 1
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      Menu item 2
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
      Menu item 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="antimenu">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 68%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 16%;
  min-width: 10rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#antimenu {
  display: flex;
  visibility: hidden;
  flex-basis: 16%;
  min-width: 10rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.menu-item {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

In Chrome this looks ok:

[image]

… but Safari gets confused:

[image]

This vertical layout is used when a page gets too narrow. A slightly bigger example using a media query can be found here (the `antimenu` is just used for making sure that `content` ends up in the centre): https://jsfiddle.net/6h84h2w6/2/

What is wrong here? I guess it's my CSS that is wrong since it's such a small example…

Comment: I believe this problem is solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32689686/overlapping-css-flexbox-items-in-safari

Comment: Remove the `flex-basis` lines. https://jsfiddle.net/6h84h2w6/4/

Comment: That's it. I reset them to `auto` when switching to the vertical layout, and that fixed the issue. Thanks!